# Bitnami Installation forcing me to flush caches while theming

Tags: 7, theming, caching

I recently set up a Drupal 7 installation on an AWS ec2 instance with Bitnami.

When I'm theming, or editing any kinds of files in the sites directory a regular browser refresh won't show the changes, I need to hit Flush all caches > Css and Javascript to view the changes.

I've disabled caching in Development > Performance, and I don't have Advanced Agregation installed or anything.

Is there something to the Bitnami installation, or ec2 that could be caching the theme files?

Comment: Browser cache most likely. [AdvAgg](http://www.kyleswitchplates.com/deep-beveled-triple-gfci-decora-rocker-switch-plate-covers/) in development mode will overcome this limitation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I use a similar setup on a non-bitnami ec2 instance for clients and don't have to flush caches like this, so I don't think it's my browser. This also happens across my laptop, desktop, firefox, & chrome. I'll give AdvAgg a shot though, it might be a decent workaround for whatever's causing it.

Comment: Update: figured it out, apparently Bitnami comes with PageSpeed pre-installed and enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update for anyone who comes here in the future:

Bitnami comes with Google PageSpeed installed & enabled by default It's a pretty useful tool, but it's tricky to figure out what's caching your css when there's nothing apparent.

To check for it, take a look at the  of your drupal site & look through the `<meta>` & `<style>` tags for compressed css files, they'll look like `lkjsdhf.gkdfsgklkshr.pagespeed.kljhasdfgk.ljsdhflgk` or somesuch.

To disable it, navigate to your installation's apache configuration folder, mine was `/home/bitnami/stack/apache2/conf` & edit `pagespeed.conf`

Look for the line `ModPagespeed on` (mine was line 20) and change `on` to `off`

After that, restart Apache. You can also log into AWS and reboot your instance.

Comment: For some reason, I had to clear the Drupal cache with `drush cr` after restarting Apache, but this works. Thanks!